# How to give Controller/method in URL while calling AJAX using Item Services in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

If I need to give controller/method path like the following

$.ajax({

```
            url: "/sitecore/api/ssc/controller/method-name",
            type: "GET",
```

What exact format is needed in URL if using Item Service? as above format is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The format for Item Service Ajax URL is :
    "/sitecore/api/ssc/controllernamespace/{controllerclassname}/{id}/actionname"